# Welches Genus hat der Ersatz eines Titels durch dessen Autor? Warum ist der Duden männlich?

Tags: gender

Der Verfasser hieß ja Konrad Duden, doch das sagt wohl einem nichts über den Ursprung des Genus von *Duden*. Wenn man sich auf ein Buch beziehen will, dachte ich mir nachdem ich folgenden Satz

> wenn Du eine Autorität suchst, dann ist das *Rudin*

auf [dieser Seite](http://matheplanet.com/default3.html?call=viewtopic.php?topic=105691&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D1%26ved%3D0CCEQFjAA) gelesen habe, schafft man da ein sächliches Nomen. 
Hier bezieht sich der Satz auf ein wohl-bekanntes Buch des Autors Walter Rudin.

Ist dann der Duden ein besonderer Fall, oder sind die Bücher männlicher Autoren grundsätzlich maskulin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deine Annahme ist falsch. Alle Buchautoren geben männliche Bücher; manchmal sogar männliche Werke. Beispiele:

> Du hast wohl deine**n** Goethe nicht gelesen?
>   »De**n** *Mortimer* können Sie innerhalb des Münchner Hochschulnetzes auch als *E-Book* lesen« ([Quelle](http://cup.uni-muenchen.de/ac/kluefers/homepage/L_ac1.html))

Das funktioniert auch für mehrere Autoren eines Buches:

> Sie sollten sich zum Grundpraktikum ein Lehrbuch besorgen; wir empfehlen de**n** Jander-Blasius (wurde von Jander und Blasius geschrieben)
>   **Der** Hollemann-Wiberg sagt dir alles, was du wissen musst. (Die Autoren heißen überraschenderweise Hollemann und Wiberg.)

Und, wie in Kommentaren mir nahegebracht wurde (danke dafür!), auch für Autorinnen:

> Der neue Allende ist ein Krimi (von Isabel Allende; [Quelle](http://www.mdr.de/mdr-figaro/literatur/allende-amandas-suche100.html))
>   Der neue Läckberg, fesselnd wie eh und je (von Camilla Läckberg; [Quelle](http://www.vorablesen.de/buecher/die-engelmacherin/leseeindruecke/der-neue-laeckberg-fesselnd-wie-eh-und-je))

Dein Satz erklärt sich dadurch, dass das *das* kein Artikel, sondern ein Demonstrativpronomen ist. Hilfreich ist die Umstellung:

> Du suchst eine Autorität? Das ist **der** *Rudin*.

Du kannst den Satz aber auch unumgestellt stehenlassen:

> Wenn du eine Autorität suchst, dann ist *das **der*** Rudin.

(Wobei ich mir nicht ganz sicher bin, ob ich den Rudin als Autorität bezeichnen würde, wenn ich mich auf das Buch beziehe, aber das nur am Rande.)

Comment: Mortimer, Hollemann-Wiberg und Jander-Blasius sind mir auch aus meinem Chemie-Studium noch lebhaft in Erinnerung, obwohl das schon 30 Jahre her ist.

Comment: Es gibt im IT-Bereich ein Standardwerk, das eine Frau geschrieben hat: es heißt »Lehrbuch der Objektmodellierung: Analyse und Entwurf mit der UML 2« und wurde von Heide Balzert geschrieben. Allerdings hat sie auch andere Lehrbücher geschrieben, so dass »der Balzert« oder »die Balzert« nicht eindeutig ein bestimmtes Buch bezeichnen. Dazu kommt, dass auch ihr Ehemann, Helmut Balzert, mehrere Lehrbücher geschrieben hat, und es gibt sogar Bücher, die haben beide gemeinsam geschrieben. Ein anderes Beispiel für ein von einer Frau geschriebenes Standardwerk fällt mir leider nicht ein.

Comment: Auch wenn mir gerade kein Beispiel einfällt, bin ich mir recht sicher, dass „der xxx“ auch benutzt wird, wenn „xxx“ eine Frau ist. Man meint ja schließlich nicht die Person damit.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Wenn man nicht bei Lehrbüchern oder sonstigen "Standardwerken" in irgendeinem Bereich bleibt, sondern zu Romanen wechselt, findet man die Formulierung auch einfacher für Autorinnen: ["Der neue Allende ist ein Krimi"](http://www.mdr.de/mdr-figaro/literatur/allende-amandas-suche100.html) (Isabel Allende); ["Der neue Läckberg, fesselnd wie eh und je......"](http://www.vorablesen.de/buecher/die-engelmacherin/leseeindruecke/der-neue-laeckberg-fesselnd-wie-eh-und-je) (Camilla Läckberg) etc.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Danke für diese Beispiele! Sind eingefügt.

Comment: @userunknown Danke. Männlich ist entfernt.

Comment: Es fehlt leider noch eine Erklärung, warum das so ist, also wieso Buchtitel männlich sind.

Comment: @userunknown Wenn du sie beitragen kannst, bitte gerne. Ich kenne sie nicht, deswegen habe ich sie nicht dazugeschrieben. Denn weder *das Buch* noch *das Werk* taugen dazu. *Der Roman* ggf, aber das würde ja wieder von *der Novelle* konterkariert. Oder handelt es sich schlichtweg um *den Titel?*