# Gender of complete titles for books/songs/movies etc

Tags: noun

How does one determine the gender when referring to the complete titles of books, songs, movies, etc.?

Do they follow the underlying *das Buch*, *der Film*, *die Theorie*, etc.? Or do they follow the nouns in the actual title?

For example, say you published a book titled "Katzen und Hunde". Which is correct (when pointing to the book) if one doesn't want to use a relative clause?

> Das ist **mein/meine** "Katzen und Hunde".

Comment: What is the relation to the relative clause? (das Buch, das K&H heißt?)

Comment: Yes, so referring to the underlying object, with a title in the relative clause.

Comment: Related (although in German) https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22685/welches-genus-hat-der-ersatz-eines-titels-durch-dessen-autor-warum-ist-der-dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the gender goes according to the gender of the medium you refer to:

> Das *ist mein* (Buch) "Katzen und Hunde".
>
> Das *ist meine* (DVD) "Katzen und Hunde".
>
> Das *sind meine* (Zeitschriften der Reihe) "Katzen und Hunde".

Nevertheless, in German it is not very common to omit the mention of the medium. At least I would always mention it:

> Das *ist mein* Buch "Katzen und Hunde".
>
> Das *ist meine* DVD über Katzen und Hunde.
>
> Das *sind meine* Katzen-und-Hunde-Zeitschriften.

There is an exception when the book, DVD or whatever is known by a name:<sup>1</sup>

> Das *ist mein* Duden.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>see: [Welches Genus hat der Ersatz eines Titels durch dessen Autor? Warum ist der Duden männlich?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22685/welches-genus-hat-der-ersatz-eines-titels-durch-dessen-autor-warum-ist-der-dude)</sup>

Comment: Bei den unterschlagenen Kategorien besteht die Schwierigkeit, dass es mehrere Möglichkeiten gibt, und diese unterschiedlichen Geschlechts sein können: Das Buch, der Band, die Edition; die Kassette, das Band; das Bild, der Druck, die Malerei usw.

Comment: @userunknown, guter Punkt. Ein Grund mehr sie immer zu erwähnen.